# Laravel is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, vue.js

Well i am playing with the new laravel 5.3 and vue.js and i want to do a GET call to some users i have in my DB

Im using components btw.

This is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/UserComponents/User.vue'));

const app = new Vue({

    el: 'body',

});
```

This is my component User.vue i left the HTML template out for post size reason i can post it if neccesary

```
<script>

    export default{

        data : function () {
            return {
                users : ''
            }
        },

        methods: {


            fetchUser: function () {

                var vm = this;

                vm.$http.get('user/', function (data) {
                   vm.$set('users', data)
                })

            }
        },
        ready() {

            this.fetchUser();
        },

    }
</script>
```

Im getting 2 errors in the console

```
 vue-resource.common.js?d39b:27 0ReferenceError: Laravel is not defined(…)

(program):29 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Laravel is not defined(…)
```

this is my package.json as you can see i have all the deps for this to work vue and vue resource

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
  }
}
```

Hope someone could help me out here. Thank you

Comment: Can you show your `./bootstrap.js`. Somewhere the variable/constant `Laravel` is being used without it being initialised.

Comment: @NEOJPK, can you please post your HTML template? I'm also playing with same. So it will help me to learn.

Comment: I dont have it anymore dude. But i think they fixed it. Go and grab the latest versión from composer. And then npm install

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to put this on your blade, as you can see is inserted by default on app.blade on Laravel 5.3

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: I have had a similar problem, and i did solved in this way! Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Or for a cleaner format:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = { csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}' };
</script>
```

Does same thing as Rocco's answer.

Comment: can you please add more detail to this answer why we need to do this?

Comment: It's just cleaner.

Comment: i heard that laravel needs this to provide security

Comment: i heard that Laravel use this to provide security. Specially, we can use this while using AJAX as auth token.

Comment: @Danish yes, that's true. If you use axios, the 'recommended' ajax library for Laravel 5.4 for instance, you could define an interceptor such as: 

`axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;
    config.headers['X-REQUESTED-WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; //for flagging req as ajax

    return config;
});` as this would send the token for each ajax request. This interceptor comes default with the latest framework version.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using axios then ensure the following is in your bootstrap.js file after axios is imported:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```