# Laravel is not defined while applying real time chat

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my code,

```
window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([

            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            'user' => [
            'authenticated' => auth()->check(),
            'id' => auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
            'name' => auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->name : null
            ],

            'keys' => [
                'pusher' => config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key')
            ]

         ])!!};
```

here is code in bootstrap.js

```
 import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

  window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: Laravel.keys.pusher
  });
```

and I get this error

```
app.js:28113 Uncaught ReferenceError: Laravel is not defined
    at Object.VERSION (app.js:28113)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:28043)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:28028)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:63
    at app.js:66
```

Says

```
window.Echo = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_laravel_echo___default.a({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: Laravel.keys.pusher(here says Uncaught ReferenceError: Laravel is not defined)
});
```

I tried solutions as its in this [Laravel is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137883/laravel-is-not-defined) , but It didnt work.. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your mix script is in the footer? ie. after you define ```Laravel```

Comment: Uhmm I think no, but I exactly didnt understand how to do it as you say, can you explain tell me bit detailed? Cuz I am not so expert in these things.. :)